# Acquire command line of remote process in Windows OS

Tags: windows, process, processhacker

I'd like to use C/C++/CS API to get the command line that invoked another process according to PID.

I've seen that this is done in processHacker that is an openSource project, but I couldn't find the exact way for how it's done. Perhaps anyone can share the undocumented method with me ? thanks !

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21945606/how-can-i-get-the-full-command-line-of-all-the-processes-after-doing-a-process-w) answer your question?